# ERROR: giving up after 0 fragment retries

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

I have a problem with the [`yotube_dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme) library. All worked fine, but I later got an error. I search for a solution and found that I must install the master `youtube_dl` version. I did it, but I got a new error that I can't fix.

```
ERROR: giving up after 0 fragment retries.
```

I don't know why this comes. Please help! Here is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

TOKEN = 'token here'
intents = discord.Intents.all()


class MusicBot(commands.Bot):
    initial_extensions = ['cogs.playcommand']

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Music online!')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(f'Message from {message.author}: {message.content}')
        await self.process_commands(message)


##################################################

client = MusicBot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


async def main():
    async with client:
        for extension in client.initial_extensions:
            await client.load_extension(extension)
        await client.start(TOKEN)


asyncio.run(main())
```

So this is my main.py file

Here is my cog file:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl


class PlayCommand(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        try:
            voicec = ctx.author.voice
            if voicec:
                channel = voicec.channel
                if channel:
                    songname = f'songs/{ctx.guild.id}_current.mp3'
                    song_there = os.path.isfile(songname)
                    try:
                        if song_there:
                            os.remove(songname)
                            print('Removed old song file')
                    except PermissionError:
                        print('Trying to delete file, but it is being played')
                        await ctx.send('Error: Music playing')
                        return

                    voice = await channel.connect()
                    ydl_opts = {
                        'format': "bestaudio/best",
                        'extractor_retries': 'auto',
                        'postprocessors': [{
                            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                            'preferredquality': '192'
                        }]
                    }

                    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                        print('Downloading audio now\n')
                        ydl.download([url])

                    for file in os.listdir('./'):
                        if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                            print(f'Renamed file: {file}\n')
                            os.rename(file, songname)

                    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(songname), after=lambda e: print('Song zu ende.'))
                    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)

                    print('Ok.')


        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error: {e}')
            await ctx.send('Error can't play audio file')


async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(PlayCommand(client))
```

I tried searching on GitHub and other social networks. But don't find anything that helps me fix my problem.

Comment: have you tried another format than "bestaudio/best" ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.